# How do I print the SQL query of a view in front end?

Tags: views, 8, debugging

I have installed latest Drupal 8.1.1 also Devel module installed there is no any option for Display query log on devel setting page while it's present on D7 Devel module.
I have created a view with relationship now I want to display SQL Query of that view at the front end.

How do I print the SQL query of a view in front end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Devel module includes the webprofiler module; you have to enable that to see the query log.

Note that [there's currently a bug in core](https://www.drupal.org/node/2682373) in 8.1 that prevents it from being used.

Answer (score 8):

While you could install webprofiler module, if you've already got a custom module, it might be quicker to do this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_post_execute().
 */
function MY_MODULE_views_post_execute(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() != 'MY_SPECIAL_VIEW') {
    return;
  }
  dpq($view->query->query());
}
```

Comment: You can also ` dump((string)$view->query->query());`

Answer (score 7):

You can enable on "Show the SQL query" and "Show other queries run during render during live preview" on "www.example.com/admin/structure/views/settings"

[image]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thnx for the fast reply,  all the options are already enabled("Show the SQL query" and "Show other queries run during render during live preview") this is only for admin preview I want this one for end user(authenticated and anonymous user).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the database abstraction layer to run your own queries, you can do use the addTag method and pass in 'debug', too.

$query->addTag('debug')

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code to print the plain query in frontend in Drupal 8.
In order to use the dpq or dpm function, the devel module should be installed in the site.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_post_execute().
 */
function MY_MODULE_views_post_execute(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() == 'YOUR_VIEW_MACHINE_NAME') {
    // To print query with placeholder.
    dpm($view->query->query()->__toString());
    // To print query with dynamic argument values
    dpq($view->query->query());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do `dpq($query->query());`
That will put the query in the message area of your frontend.
Edit - You will need devel module to use this feature.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for the **Drupal 7** equivalent of Dalin's answer, the structure is just a little different.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_post_execute().
 */
function MY_MODULE_views_post_execute($view) {
  if ($view->name != 'MY_SPECIAL_VIEW') {
    return;
  }
  dpq($view->build_info['query']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $db->query('MY QUERY');
print_r($query); // In the result you'll see a key "queryString" containing the actual query
```